# Unable to delete files via FTP?

Tags: linux-mint, ftp, vsftpd

I have a couple of FTP users who can access my (pseudo) server running vsftpd under Mint Linux. They are restricted to a specific directory and below via chroot(). Whilst they can access the files without problem they are unable to delete them when they are no longer required. The permissions on their base directory, and all sub-directories is 'drwxrwxrwx' and all files '_rw_rw_rw_'. I have searched the web but been unable to find an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the users local users or vsftp users ?

Try the following:

```
grep local_enable /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
```

That should be set to YES and the users should log in with local accounts for this to work.

If you do not want this or already have this set, please paste your `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf` here.

Comment: Thank you. Set  local_enable=YES and everything working as restarting vsftpd.